# How to add a Domain Account user into a Local Group?

Tags: authentication, vbscript, adsi

There are hundreds of articles out there that teach that but my case is "unique". So I was getting access denied on the line below:

```
Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & domainControllerIP & "/" & domainAccount & ",user")
```

So I realized I had to pass the credentials of the user. Most people pass only the DomainName which is fine. It will connect to a Domain Controller which can be known by looking at the environment variable %LOGONSERVER%. I need to specify the Domain Controller name (or IP) otherwise it won't work for us.

So I am just trying to get this sintax right. Here is my code:

```
Sub AddAccountToLocalGroup(domainName, domainControllerIP, localGroup, domainAccount)

  Dim localComputer : localComputer = GetMachineName()
  Dim objLocalGroup
  Dim objDomainUser

  const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = &h0001
  const ADS_SERVER_BIND           = &h0200

  Set objLocalGroup = GetObject("WinNT://" & localComputer      & "/" & localGroup    & ",group")
 'Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & domainControllerIP & "/" & domainAccount & ",user")   'ACCESS DENIED

'Error happens in Set objDomainUser
' Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & domainName & "/" & domainControllerIP & "/" & "Bob", "Bob", "Password", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION or ADS_SERVER_BIND)
' Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & domainName & "/" & domainControllerIP & "/" & "Bob", "Bob", "Password", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION or ADS_SERVER_BIND)
' Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & domainName & "/" & domainControllerIP & "/" & ",user", "Bob", "Password", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION or ADS_SERVER_BIND)
' Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT:").OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & domainName & "/" & "Bob" & ",user", "Bob", "Password", ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION or ADS_SERVER_BIND)


  'Add domain user to local group
  objLocalGroup.Add(objDomainUser.ADsPath)

  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
       WScript.Echo Err.Number
  Else
       WScript.Echo domainAccount & " has been added to local group."
  End If
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to connect to AD using explicit credentials against a specific DC like this:

```
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = &h0001
Const ADS_SERVER_BIND           = &h0200

server   = "..."
username = "DOMAIN\user"
password = "password"

Set rootDSE = GetObject("LDAP:").OpenDSObject("LDAP://" & server & "/RootDSE" _
  , username, password, ADS_SERVER_BIND + ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)
base   = "<LDAP://" & server & "/" & rootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext") & ">"
filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
attr   = "distinguishedName"
scope  = "subtree"

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
conn.Properties("User ID")   = username
conn.Properties("Password")  = password
conn.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
conn.Properties("ADSI Flag") = ADS_SERVER_BIND + ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION
conn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = base & ";" & filter & ";" & attr & ";" & scope
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
cmd.Properties("Timeout") = 30
cmd.Properties("Cache Results") = False

Set rs = cmd.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  'enumerate AD records returned by query
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close

conn.Close
```

See [this article](http://www.rlmueller.net/ADOAltCredentials.htm) from Richard L. Mueller.

**Edit:** Ah, my mistake. The above is for the LDAP provider, which can't handle local groups. Also an LDAP `ADsPath` can't be added to a group object obtained from the WinNT provider. The reason why your attempts didn't work is because you tried `WinNT://DOMAIN/...`, but should have used `WinNT://DOMAIN_CONTROLLER/...`. Something like this should work:

```
Const ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION = &h0001
Const ADS_SERVER_BIND           = &h0200

dc       = "..."
username = "DOMAIN\user"
password = "password"

domainuser = "Bob"
localgroup = "Users"

Set nt   = GetObject("WinNT:")
Set user = nt.OpenDSObject("WinNT://" & dc & "/" & domainuser & ",user" _
  , username, password, ADS_SERVER_BIND + ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION)

GetObject("WinNT://./" & localgroup & ",group").Add user.ADsPath
```

Comment: The only problem now is how do I get the user account object inside your loop?
Set objDomainUser = GetObject("WinNT://" & ...

Comment: well I tried that before and it gave me "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Permission denied: 'GetObject' "
Bear in mind that the VBScript (cmd.exe) is running under the SYSTEM account but that should not matter right if I am passing the credentials to access the AD objects.
Note: If I run the script when I am logged on with MY account then the script works! but I do need to make this work under SYSTEM account and pass the credentials to WinNT/LDAP,etc...

Comment: just realized that the error above was happening to servers which were trying to authenticate with a DC which is in a different AD Site. It has nothing to do with the SYSTEM account. This issue has to do with a RODC I will bet. Doing more tests.

Comment: I think the problem is password replication … actually not a problem but a security feature.  We don’t allow the users password to be replicated to an RODC and specifically block it if they are administrator or some other protected account. I think the ZDC actually proxy’s the logon request to the BDC on behalf of the user so in fact the server is reporting correctly that the BDC is ultimately it’s logon server.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/01/18/understanding-read-only-domain-controller-authentication.aspx